# MSI built in VS2015/Win10 4mb smaller than VS2010/Win 7

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, mfc, windows-installer

As the title says, my MSI that is built in **VS 2015** is a whole 4mb smaller than my MSI built in **VS 2010**. In addition to the file size difference, the Win10 installer only seems to be able to be installed on Win 8+, giving a missing DLL error on Win7. I've tried searching a number of phrases, but I can't find anything that relates to my question. Can anybody shed some light on this? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I can provide more information, but I'm not sure what you'd need, so let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 2):

A few comments of explanation:

1. MSI files are not built from scratch - they are based on a schema MSI file that's used as the starting point. If the two VS editions use different schemas you'll see different MSI files, especially if support for old stuff was deleted.
2. MSI files are sparse files, not continuous data streams. If the mechanism for updating the database (which is what MSI files are) is different then the file structure may be different, with less unused space in it.
3. MSI files contain data other than your files. There are binary files containing bitmaps, calls to detect the NET framework, C++ Dlls to call managed custom actions, all kinds of things that may be different between the two versions of Visual Studio. Any change here will change the size of the MSI file.

Is this an actual issue? I suspect that if somebody used VS 2010 and VS 2015 to generate a 100MB code file, nobody would worry if they came out as different sizes because they are different compilers with different internals.

Comment: It's not so much I'm worried about the different sizes, just on certain computers (including a client's) the installer will fail, saying 'There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor' with no indication to which DLL file. But it will work on my computer and some other computers.

Comment: That's an issue you should post. It won't be related to the size. If you have added custom actions they msy be missing a dependency on some machines. Do the install with a verbose log and look for the error: msiexec /I [path to msi file] /l*vx [path to a text log file]

Comment: Thanks for that, the biggest problem I was having is that there was such little information in the error I didn't know where to begin.